# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/.VolumeIcon.icns'

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, cypress

Any idea why I would get this when trying to run component tests in `Vue.js` using Cypress? Is this a bug related to running on MacOS Catalina? (I ask because I think VolumeIcon.icns is a OS X thing??)

```
The following error was thrown by a plugin. We stopped running your tests because a plugin crashed. Please check your plugins file (/Users/MLaw/vue-app/tests/plugins/index.js)

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/.VolumeIcon.icns'

Error: The following error was thrown by a plugin. We stopped running your tests because a plugin crashed. Please check your plugins file (`/Users/MLaw/vue-app/tests/plugins/index.js`)
    at Object.get (/Users/MLaw/Library/Caches/Cypress/5.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/errors.js:968:15)
    at EventEmitter.handleError (/Users/MLaw/Library/Caches/Cypress/5.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/index.js:159:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/MLaw/Library/Caches/Cypress/5.6.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/plugins/util.js:19:22)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:876:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
```

My `index.js` looks like:

```
    const preprocessor = require('@cypress/vue/dist/plugins/webpack');
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  preprocessor(on, config);
  // IMPORTANT return the config object
  return config
};
```

Comment: Oh, and by the way, that file does exist at /.VolumeIcon.icns .... it is a link to its real location.

Comment: Where did you get this - on win / Linux / xos? Where this file is - in the project directory?

Comment: @vovchisko. Its on OSX

Comment: I was getting the same error inside my cypress window. However, when I looked in my terminal I found a different error that had to do with my cypress babel config. Perhaps you have the same issue and this error isn't the real cause of the problem.

Comment: Same as @MMansour got error, but from terminal it was clear I had missing dependencies, so just reinstall dependencies (in my case yarn) and it worked!

Comment: I was getting same error. In my case VSCode was auto importing `import { config } from 'webpack` when I typed "config". 
I removed that import statement it worked fine.

Answer (score 24):

```
sudo touch /.VolumeIcon.icns
```

I use M1 MacOS, it works for me.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! what does this happen for?